# Fulfillment error occurred when trying to test google action in voice assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

I'm trying to create a webhook that will get the Intent and current state, change the state, and send back a reply using actions-on-google library for node.js.

**index.js** is as follows:

```
'use strict';

const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

app.intent('welcome', conv => {
  let replyState = setReplyState( conv, 'prompt' );
  let intent = getIntentName( conv );
  sendReply( conv, intent, replyState );
});


function getReplyState( conv ){
  return conv.data['replyState'];
}

function setReplyState( conv, state ){
  conv.data['replyState'] = state;
  return state;
}

function getIntentName( conv ){
  return conv.intent;
}

const welcomeReplies = [
  "Welcome!"
];


const allReplies = {
  welcome: welcomeReplies,
};

function sendReply( conv, intent, replyState ){

  let repliesNamed = replyState;
  let replies = allReplies[repliesNamed];
  conv.add( reply );
}

exports.fulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(action);
```

**package.json** is as follows:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
        "node": "8"
      },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~6.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.3",
    "actions-on-google": "~2.5.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Error occurred:

> MalformedResponse
>       Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of invalid platform response: Could not find a RichResponse or SystemIntent in the platform response for agentId: ab93fe46-9eb1-4a6c-aea7-1699d67d7369 and intentId: 1ec758db-d03a-40b7-85fe-189d9245e6e2.

I referred https://github.com/afirstenberg/examples/tree/master/conversation-to-code-2-aog

Comment: You may want to update the question with any error logs from the run of the function itself, and not just errors that you get in the Action test console.

Comment: (On a personal note - thanks for reading my article and source. I do hope it's helping.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the function execution log, but it looks like `action` isn't defined anywhere, so the call `functions.https.onRequest(action);` returns an error.

In the source you're working from, `action` is defined as

```
const action = dialogflow();
```

and all the Intent Handlers are registered with

```
action.intent(...)
```

While you have a similar definition

```
const app = dialogflow({debug: true});
```

so you can probably change the line that defines the function to

```
exports.fulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

to resolve your immediate problem.